# Jump buffer not playing nice with variable jumping

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-language

I'm having an issue where my player object always jumps to maximum height when jumping because of my buffer. This is my first game, so I'm playing around with Heartbeast's engine. I figure I'm missing something fairly obvious, and just hoping y'all can help!

Here's what I'm working with in my jump action script:

---

```
///enable_movement_jump(height, input, release_input)
/*
    Call this script to enable platform jumping
    on a movement entity.
*/

var height = argument[0]; // The jump height (Should be positive)
var input = argument[1]; // The input for jumping
var release_input = argument[2]; // The input for jump height control (release)
var coyoteFrames = 10; // The grace period, in frames, for coyote time
var jumpBufferFrames = 10; // The buffer, in frames, for the jump buffer

// Check for ground collision
if (place_meeting(x, y+1, collision_object) || place_meeting(xprevious, yprevious+1, collision_object)) {
    coyoteTimer = 0; // Reset coyote timer
    if ((input) || (jumpBufferTimer < jumpBufferFrames))
    {
        vsp[0] = -height;
        coyoteTimer = coyoteFrames; // Max coyote timer
        jumpBufferTimer = jumpBufferFrames; // Max buffer timer
    }

} else {
    if (input)
    {
        jumpBufferTimer = 0; // Reset buffer timer
        if (coyoteTimer < coyoteFrames) // During coyote time
        {
            vsp[0] = -height;
            coyoteTimer = coyoteFrames; // Max coyote timer
            jumpBufferTimer = jumpBufferFrames; // Max buffer timer
        }
    }
    if (release_input && vsp[0] <= -height/3) {
        vsp[0] = -height/3;
    }
}

++coyoteTimer; // Increase coyote
++jumpBufferTimer; // Increase buffer
```

---

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with the release_input not being triggered?

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the ground, you reset the `coyoteTimer`, but you place the `jumpBufferTimer` in a different condition, perhaps these should be set to 0 under the same conditions?